# When to create an Index and when not to

Tags: mongodb

Im using MongoDB Native 2.0+. 
I have a collection named `services`. This collection contains document with references to `clients` in another collection. That means, each service are "owned" by one client.

There will around 50-200 clients. 
Each client can theoretically "own" around 1-50 services, but in reality it will likely be around 1-10 for most clients.

Each service have two fields which act as unique identifiers. One is `_id` which is used in admin URL's and as immutable reference between documents. The other one is `slug` which is a simpler identifier mostly used for public URL for more readability.

I mainly have two kinds of queries against this collection:

```
db.services.find({client: clientID, _id: id}).toArray(callback)
db.services.find({client: clientID, slug: slug}).toArray(callback)
```

I **think** that i have to create the following **two** compound indexes for optimal queries:

```
db.services.ensureIndex({client: 1, _id: 1})
db.services.ensureIndex({client: 1, slug: 1})
```

But considering the likely small(?) number of services "owned" by each client. Maybe it will suffice with only one index. Either...

```
db.services.ensureIndex({client: 1})
```

or just this one compound index

```
db.services.find({client: clientID, slug: slug}).toArray(callback)
```

... because the `slug` queries will likely be used a lot more than the `_id.

What indexes would you create?

Thank you for all tips regarding this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that both the `_id` and the `slug` are going to be unique in the services collection, so I don't understand how a search for the `client` value is going to improve performance over just having simple indexes on `_id` and `slug` individually.

And of course `_id` will have an index out of the box, so I would think you'd only need to create the `{slug: 1}` index.